# Wamp failing on a Wordpress plugin (BackUpBuddy)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

so I had the same setup running on my computer all the same versions, for wordpress, wamp & backup buddy. But I had to reinstall my operating system cause of one virus and other things, wanted a clean start. Any ways after I did that, when ever I'm designing locally using 'wamp' and want to do a backup to push things online. It fails on me, saying that 'The backup has halted'. If I upload the same version of wordpress and backup buddy to one of my online servers, they work fine. This is why I think the problem is with 'Wamp' and need help with someone who understands php and what the error is trying to tell me. Please help me, I've been going thru forums and blogs for weeks now and haven't be able to come to a resolution for this.

**Below is the status log that I got from BackUp Buddy:**

```
Time    Elapsed Memory      Message
21:36:48    0.22sec 24.37MB BackupBuddy v4.2.12.1 using WordPress v3.9.1 on WINNT.
21:36:48    0.23sec 24.37MB Performing pre-backup procedures.
21:36:48    0.23sec 24.37MB Full backup mode.
21:36:48    0.23sec 24.37MB Flushing will not be skipped (default).
21:36:48    0.24sec 24.37MB Verifying directories ...
21:36:48    0.24sec 24.37MB Directories verified.
21:36:48    0.24sec 24.37MB Backup serial generated: `gfbgxrcdcr`.
21:36:48    0.25sec 24.37MB About to load fileoptions data in create mode.
21:36:48    0.42sec 24.37MB Fileoptions data loaded.
21:36:48    0.42sec 24.37MB Resetting statistics for last backup time and number of edits since last backup.
21:36:48    0.57sec 24.40MB Active WordPress plugins: `BackUp_Buddy_v4.2.12.1/backupbuddy.php`.
21:36:48    0.58sec 24.40MB Initial zip exclusions (after filter): `C:\wamp\www\raul/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_backups/; /wp-content/uploads/pb_backupbuddy/; /importbuddy/; /importbuddy.php`.
21:36:48    0.59sec 24.41MB Calculating mysql database tables to backup.
21:36:48    0.59sec 24.41MB Base database dump mode (before inclusions/exclusions): `prefix`.
21:36:48    0.59sec 24.41MB Determining database tables with prefix `jws_`.
21:36:48    0.70sec 24.41MB Base database tables based on settings (11 tables): `jws_commentmeta,jws_comments,jws_links,jws_options,jws_postmeta,jws_posts,jws_term_relationships,jws_term_taxonomy,jws_terms,jws_usermeta,jws_users`
21:36:48    0.70sec 24.41MB Database tables after addition (11 tables): `jws_commentmeta,jws_comments,jws_links,jws_options,jws_postmeta,jws_posts,jws_term_relationships,jws_term_taxonomy,jws_terms,jws_usermeta,jws_users`
21:36:48    0.71sec 24.41MB Database tables after exclusion (11 tables): `jws_commentmeta,jws_comments,jws_links,jws_options,jws_postmeta,jws_posts,jws_term_relationships,jws_term_taxonomy,jws_terms,jws_usermeta,jws_users`
21:36:48    0.71sec 24.44MB Breaking out tables DISABLED based on settings.
21:36:48    0.71sec 24.44MB Integrity check will be performed based on settings for this profile.
21:36:48    0.72sec 24.46MB Fileoptions saved.
21:36:48    0.83sec 24.46MB Creating DAT (data) file snapshotting site & backup information.
21:36:48    0.84sec 24.46MB wp-config.php found in normal location.
21:36:48    0.84sec 24.46MB DAT file contents (sans database user/pass): Array; (;     [backupbuddy_version] => 4.2.12.1;     [backup_time] => 1402436208;     [backup_type] => full;     [profile] => Array;         (;             [type] => full;             [title] => Complete Backup;             [skip_database_dump] => 0;             [mysqldump_additional_includes] => ;             [mysqldump_additional_excludes] => ;             [backup_nonwp_tables] => 0;             [excludes] => ;             [integrity_check] => 1;             [profile_globaltables] => 1;             [profile_globalexcludes] => 1;             [backup_mode] => 2;         ); ;     [serial] => gfbgxrcdcr;     [trigger] => manual;     [wp-config_in_parent] => ;     [abspath] => C:\wamp\www\raul/;     [siteurl] => http://localhost/raul;     [homeurl] => http://localhost/raul;     [blogname] => raul;     [blogdescription] => Just another WordPress site;     [active_plugins] => BackUp_Buddy_v4.2.12.1/backupbuddy.php;     [db_prefix] => jws_;     [db_server] => localhost;     [db_name] => raul;     [db_user] => ;     [db_password] => ;     [db_exclusions] => ;     [db_inclusions] => ;     [breakout_tables] => Array;         (;         ); ;     [tables_sizes] => Array;         (;             [jws_commentmeta] => 49152;             [jws_comments] => 81920;             [jws_links] => 32768;             [jws_options] => 344064;             [jws_postmeta] => 49152;             [jws_posts] => 81920;             [jws_term_relationships] => 32768;             [jws_term_taxonomy] => 49152;             [jws_terms] => 49152;             [jws_usermeta] => 49152;             [jws_users] => 49152;         ); ;     [is_multisite] => ;     [is_multisite_export] => ;     [domain] => ;     [path] => ;     [upload_url] => ;     [upload_url_rewrite] => ; );
21:36:48    0.85sec 24.46MB Finished creating DAT (data) file.
21:36:48    0.86sec 24.46MB Generating ImportBuddy tool to include in backup archive: `C:\wamp\www\raul/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_temp/gfbgxrcdcr/importbuddy.php`.
21:36:48    0.86sec 24.46MB Attempted to set PHP execution time to 7200
21:36:48    0.87sec 24.46MB Reported PHP execution time - Configured: 120; Original: 120; Current: 7200
21:36:48    0.87sec 24.46MB Attempted to set PHP memory limit to user defined WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT (256M) or over-ridden value
21:36:48    0.87sec 24.46MB Reported PHP memory limits - Configured: 128M; Original: 256M; Current: 256M
21:36:49    1.72sec 29.43MB ImportBuddy generation complete.
21:36:49    1.72sec 29.43MB Fileoptions saved.
21:36:49    1.72sec 29.43MB Finished pre-backup procedures.
21:36:49    1.73sec 29.43MB Running in modern backup mode based on settings. Mode value: `2`. Trigger: `manual`.
21:36:49    1.73sec 29.43MB Scheduling Cron for `gfbgxrcdcr`.
21:36:49    1.73sec 29.43MB Loading DB kicker in case database has gone away.
21:36:49    1.77sec 29.43MB Database kicker database object class: `wpdb`.
21:36:49    1.79sec 29.43MB Database Server has gone away, attempting to reconnect.
21:36:49    1.82sec 29.43MB Database Server reconnection failed.
21:36:49    1.82sec 29.43MB ERROR: Database Server has gone away, unable to schedule next backup step. The backup cannot continue. This is most often caused by mysql running out of memory or timing out far too early. Please contact your host.
```

**Below is the php error that I'm getting:**

```
( ! ) Warning: mysql_ping() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp\www\raul\wp-content\plugins\BackUp_Buddy_v4.2.12.1\lib\wpdbutils\wpdbutils.php on line 97
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  308064  {main}( )   ..\admin.php:0
2   0.2520  23546184    do_action( )    ..\admin.php:211
3   0.2520  23547680    call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\raul\wp-includes\plugin.php:470} ( )  ..\plugin.php:470
4   0.2520  23547928    backup ( )  ..\plugin.php:470
5   0.2520  23548472    pb_backupbuddy_pagescore->__call( ) ..\plugin.php:0
6   0.2540  23562256    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\raul\wp-content\plugins\BackUp_Buddy_v4.2.12.1\controllers\pages\backup.php' )   ..\core_controllers.php:226
7   0.2785  23651920    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\raul\wp-content\plugins\BackUp_Buddy_v4.2.12.1\controllers\pages\_backup-perform.php' )  ..\backup.php:34
8   0.3130  25476056    pb_backupbuddy_backup->start_backup_process( )  ..\_backup-perform.php:773
9   1.8249  25591400    pb_backupbuddy_backup->cron_next_step( )    ..\backup.php:171
10  1.8660  25609784    pluginbuddy_wpdbutils->kick( )  ..\backup.php:935
11  1.8660  25610032    mysql_ping ( )  ..\wpdbutils.php:97

( ! ) Warning: mysql_ping() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp\www\raul\wp-content\plugins\BackUp_Buddy_v4.2.12.1\lib\wpdbutils\wpdbutils.php on line 111
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  308064  {main}( )   ..\admin.php:0
2   0.2520  23546184    do_action( )    ..\admin.php:211
3   0.2520  23547680    call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\raul\wp-includes\plugin.php:470} ( )  ..\plugin.php:470
4   0.2520  23547928    backup ( )  ..\plugin.php:470
5   0.2520  23548472    pb_backupbuddy_pagescore->__call( ) ..\plugin.php:0
6   0.2540  23562256    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\raul\wp-content\plugins\BackUp_Buddy_v4.2.12.1\controllers\pages\backup.php' )   ..\core_controllers.php:226
7   0.2785  23651920    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\raul\wp-content\plugins\BackUp_Buddy_v4.2.12.1\controllers\pages\_backup-perform.php' )  ..\backup.php:34
8   0.3130  25476056    pb_backupbuddy_backup->start_backup_process( )  ..\_backup-perform.php:773
9   1.8249  25591400    pb_backupbuddy_backup->cron_next_step( )    ..\backup.php:171
10  1.8660  25609784    pluginbuddy_wpdbutils->kick( )  ..\backup.php:935
11  1.8894  25610032    mysql_ping ( )  ..\wpdbutils.php:111
```

I've tried increasing memory limits. Restarting the services. I've also clean installed this over and over again. Maybe I'm doing something wrong setting up the databases? Please help. Thanks.!

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with PHP version that you are using. Try to revert it back to PHP version to 5.4+ and it will gonna work again.

Hope it helps,

Remiel

Comment: Thanks for this, it put an end to hours of trying to figure this issue out!

Comment: No problem @JonathanKehayias glad to help